# JQuery removeclass addclass not working in ie

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making this overview where the title appears on the bottom of an image when you hover the image.

It's working fine in all browsers except internet explorer.

This is what I've got so far:
html:

```
    <div class="category">
      <a href="?pageId">
        <span class="Image"><img src="image.jpg" />
          <span class="Title">Page Title</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

css:

```
    .category {width:220px; float:left; margin-right:20px;}
    .category a .Image {position:relative; }
    .category a .Image img {display:block; width:220px; height:auto;}
    .category a .Title {display:none;}
    .category a .viewTitle {display:block; height:40px; padding:5px 10px; position:absolute; top:-50px;}
```

jquery:

```
    $( ".category a .Image" ).hover(function(){
      $(this).find('.Title').addClass("viewTitle");
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.Title').removeClass("viewTitle");
    });
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

**EDIT: error in mark-up -> .Title is inside .Image, sorry for mix-up.**

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: just check that other css not affect the styles of class you are adding and removing.. try using !important with styles..

Comment: tested in IE versions 10+11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.category {width:220px; float:left; margin-right:20px; position: relative;}
```

you have the image as positioned relative. your `.title` is outside of the container so it wont "work" as expected

```
.category a .viewTitle {display:block; height:40px; padding:5px 10px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0;}
```

since your "container" is now positioned relative you can use absolute positioning.

---

after the edit.. i would use this isntead

```
.Title { display:none; }
.Image:hover .Title { display:block; }
```

unless you want the js stuff i dont think it will be needed

http://jsbin.com/wumup/1/edit?html,css,output

you also need to change the spans to divs

Comment: see my 2nd part above.. you dont even need the JS for it. just use CSS. just position it in `.Title` aswell.

Comment: Isn't the .Image (position:relative) acting as the 'container' for .viewTitle? edit and answer mixed

Comment: i added a jsbin eg for it.. my guess is the spans were messing you around. http://jsbin.com/wumup/1/edit?html,css,output you are already using float on the category so its as good as a span for inline. you can also change it to `.category a .Image img { width:220px; height:auto;}` (height - i just specified it for testing)

Comment: I used to have divs there, but w3 validator nags about block elements inside inline elements. Changed it to spans for that reason. Probably better to use the divs and use 1 a-tag per element.

Answer (score 2):

`.Title` element is a sibling of `.Image`, not a descendant. Use `.siblings()`

```
$( ".category a .Image" ).hover(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.Title').addClass("viewTitle");
}, function() {
  $(this).siblings('.Title').removeClass("viewTitle");
});
```

Comment: .siblings wasn't working. I noticed I had an error in my mark-up. .Title is inside .Image. Fixed it in example sorry for mix up.